# How to set value of parent argument to child method?

Tags: python, oop, super

I have a Paragraph class:

```
from googletrans import Translator

class Paragraph:

    def __init__(self, text, origin_lang='en'):
        self.text = text
        self.origin_lang = origin_lang

    def translate(self, dest_lang='ne'):
        translator = Translator()
        translation = translator.translate(text = self.text,
                                           dest=dest_lang)
        return translation.text
```

I made a subclass out of it:

```
class FileParagraph(Paragraph):

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        super().__init__(text=self.get_from_file())
        self.filepath = filepath

    def get_from_file(self):
        with open(self.filepath) as file:
            return file.read()
```

While Paragraph got the `text` directly as argument, the subclass generates the `text` from the `get_from_file` method.

However, I cannot seem to call the inherited `translate` method:

```
fp = FileParagraph("sample.txt")
print(fp.translate(dest_lang='de'))
```

That throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/main.py", line 66, in <module>
    fp = FileParagraph("sample.txt")
  File "C:/main.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(text=self.get_from_file())
  File "C:/main.py", line 25, in get_from_file
    with open(self.filepath) as file:
AttributeError: 'FileParagraph' object has no attribute 'filepath'
```

One solution is to change the subclass **init** to:

```
def __init__(self, filepath):
    self.filepath = filepath
    self.text = self.get_from_file()
```

However, that means removing the initialization of super(). Is there another solution without having to remove `super().__init__?`

Or is this not even the case to make use of inheritance?

Comment: You are calling `self.get_from_file()` before you set `self.filepath`. since `self.get_from_file()` requires that member variable to be set you get the error. This by the way has nothing to do with either inheritance or the `translate` method

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, that's the reason for the error. Are you suggesting to put `self.filepath = filepath` before `super().__init__(text=self.get_from_file())` to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, that should work

Comment: @UnholySheep Could you post that as an answer please? I'd upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from calling the `get_from_file` method, which relies on `self.filepath`, before `self.filepath` is set. Simply changing the order of the two lines in `__init__` fixes this

```
class FileParagraph(Paragraph):

    def __init__(self, filepath):
        # set member variable first
        self.filepath = filepath
        # then call super's init
        super().__init__(text=self.get_from_file())

    def get_from_file(self):
        with open(self.filepath) as file:
            return file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should also give a value for the filepath while creating the object here

```
fp = FileParagraph("sample.txt")
```

you should also input a value for the filepath along with text
eg

```
fp = FileParagraph(text = "sample.txt", filepath = "  ")
```